# skipping null values in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014

**Background:**

creating a database that has multiple identical inputs with unique identifiers, for example: `input_option_1`, `data_type_1`, `input_option_2, data_type_2`, etc...
`input_option_1`, `data_type_1` and `input_option_2` and `data_type_2` are separate rows and inputs. `input_option_1`, `data_type_1` are row 1 and `input_option_2` and `data_type_2` is row 2.

**Process:**

when i create a simple query against the data the code looks like this:

```
use DB_test2
select input_option_1, data_type_1, input_option_2, data_type_2
from dbo.page_1
```

**Output:**

the output is just as what is being called out and looks like this

```
input_option_1 data_type_1  input_option_2  data_type_2    
21             numerical    34A             alphanumeric
```

**problem:**

what i am trying to do is create one column for the `input_option_1` and `input_option_2` and one column for `data_type_1` and `data_type_2`.

**example:**

this is what i want it to look like.

```
input_option    data_type    
21              numerical    
34a             alphanumeric
```

Comment: You'd be better off normalizing your database-- you don't want to have to keep creating new columns every time you add a new input.  However, to get your desired results, look at using `union`... Something like `select opt1, type1 from table union select opt2, type2 from table`...

Comment: And the question has to do with the title... what?

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION:

```
SELECT input_option_1 AS [Input_Option],
  data_type_1 AS [Data_Type]
FROM dbo.Page_1
UNION ALL
SELECT input_option_2 AS [Input_Option],
  data_type_2 AS [Data_Type]
FROM dbo.Page_1
ORDER BY [Input_Option],
   [Data_Type]
```

This will work but as you add more columns you'd need to modify this query, it's obviously not optimal but it is a solution.